# How to get rid of “Duplicate IMA measurements will not be recorded in the IMA log.”?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, device-mapper

In the journal of my Debian 12 kernel linux-image-6.1.0-10-amd64 version 6.1.37-1 I discovered the following lines:

```
…
… hostname systemd[1]: Starting systemd-journald.service - Journal Service …
… hostname kernel: device-mapper: core: CONFIG_IMA_DISABLE_HTABLE is disabled. Duplicate IMA measurements will not be recorded in the IMA log.
```

The last line is yellow, i.e., a warning.  The machine exhibits issues later during boot (some services and Gnome fail to start) after upgrading from Debian 11 to Debian 12. Does it make any sense to try to enable CONFIG_IMA_DISABLE_HTABLE or to record duplicates otherwise?  If so, how to do it the easiest way? Is there any command-line switch for this or do we really have to recompile the kernel?